postgresql query IllegalArgumentException in Yellowbrick DB
I'm writing Pl/pgSQL joining query in Yellowbrick DB.
I have join 6 tables at a time. It was working fine.
Suddenly I observe my query is throwing error: "IllegalArgumentException"

Checked the Yellowbrick Error code  Link
But don't found too much information:

Do you have any suggestion why "IllegalArgumentException" is throwing in PL/pgSQL query in Yellowbrick DB ?
Please share something if you have any idea for this.
NB: I didn't found Yellowbrick tag, so mention pl/pgsql tag

It is data corruption or a software bug. Without a way to reproduce the error, nobody can help you. That includes Yellowbrick, whatever that is.

You probably has a bas update, report it to yellowbrick, they get will need something to reproduce the problem

Thanks @nbk to add the 'Yellowbrick' tag

I found a way to resolve the issue. I have updated the data type of joining tables keys and that way resolved the issue in my end.
According to my problem, I did every SQL joining on two primary keys, 'Year' and 'Month'. Earlier I used year(), month() function to create view table, and issue was return data type of those two functions.
First I tried to create some dummy database in MySQL & PL/pgSQL DB and when I compare with Yellowbrick found the difference of return data type, as follows:
PgAdmin4 - PL/pgSQL:

MySQL:



Yellowbrick:



When I typecast data type of those two functions as INTEGER, then my problem is solved.
Thank you all
